# MySQL search, using only letters and numbers from field values

Tags: mysql, regex, search, innodb

I have a database where a field (`plate`) has values like ABC123, ABB-123, ... Some users enter a - in between, some don't.

Now I'm building a search function where the user can perform a search, for example 'ABB123' which the search function transform to `plate` LIKE 'ABB123' but I would like that this search returns 'ABB-123' in this case.

Has someone any idea how to pull this off?

Note: database is InnoDB, so full-text search isn't possible. Since each user has his own database, I'm not planning to use a third-party search server either.

Comment: I'm thinking about using a second field like `plate_normalised` which does not contain any - signs but I'll rather avoid adding fields, because I face this problem with different fields (phone number, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you search for both instances?

```
plate = 'ABB123' OR plate = 'ABB-123'
```

Or if the format of `plate` is rather consistent, could you do something like

```
plate LIKE 'ABB%123'
```

That would get both instances.